# Check whether 'n' number of variables match a condition in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to check if 'n' number of variables is `True`.
The code I am using to get certain variables a true or false value is this:

```
    for row in range(mw):
        for col in range(mh):
            if matrix[row-1][col] == 0:
                left = False
            else:
                left = True
            if matrix[row-1][col-1] == 0:
                botleft = False
            else:
                botleft = True
            if matrix[row][col-1] == 0:
                bot = False
            else:
                bot = True
```

Now if I want to check if from these variables: `left, botleft, bot` if 2 of them are True how would I do that? If I had a larger list of variables, like 8 variables how would I check if 5 of those are True? ("matrix" is a 2d array)

Comment: Do you realise that you keep indexing the matrix at negative indexes?

Comment: To add to the above: Do you know that `matrix[-1]` is the same as `matrix[mw-1]` (last row)?

Comment: What would that change?

Comment: The question is not what would change, the question is: is that what you intend to do?

Comment: @nAZklX Your program currently thinks that the last row is right on top of the first, and the last column is right next to the first. Sometimes we want this to be true, but usually it means you made a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sum` and the fact that `False` or `True` get casted to `0` or `1`.

```
if sum([left, botleft, bot]) == 2:
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Less chars than the other answer too

Comment: @nAZklX Please carefully read the code in "the other answer". It is longer because it is explaining a concept to you through code examples. The code is there for you to read, not to copy-paste.

Comment: @leewz I understand the concept because of both answers, I think this answer is more neat than the other answer

Comment: @nAZklX The other answer's solution has fewer characters.

Answer (score 2):

You can just sum them since booleans are a subtype of integers.
For example:

```
>>> True + True + False
2
>>> True + True - True
1
>>> False + False
0


if left + botleft + bot == 2:
    pass
```

Also, it's easier if you put them in some data structure, instead of having many variables to evaluate at the end.